# Uploading RDL to PowerBI via REST returns error "Statement cannot appear within an Enum body. End of Enum assumed"

Tags: powershell, rest, reporting-services, enums, powerbi

We have a couple of hundred client-created custom SSRS reports that we need to migrate to PowerBI Paginated reports in a specific PBI workspace. To note we do not have a SSRS report server to do this from. The RDLs are extracted from our proprietary database that stores the rdl as binary. So, with a local copy of the rdls on-hand, we are trying to write a powershell script that will use the PowerBI API to load them for us. I am using the script found at [this](https://dev.to/kenakamu/upload-rdl-file-s-to-power-bi-via-api-28h) url.

I have gotten some of the reports to upload with that script just fine, but a lot of them have custom code in them that includes an ENUM list that is part of a date formatting function. Any report that has this ENUM code in it is failing. Here is the entire code block in question

```
Enum DateTimePatterns
    ShortTimeFormat = 1
    LongTimeFormat = 2
    ShortDateFormat = 3
    LongDateFormat = 4
    ShortDateShortTimeFormat = 5
    LongDateShortTimeFormat = 6
    ShortDateLongTimeFormat = 7
    LongDateLongTimeFormat = 8
End Enum

Function FormatDate(ByVal dateToFormat As DateTime, Optional ByVal FormatOption As DateTimePatterns = DateTimePatterns.ShortDateShortTimeFormat) As String
    Dim FormattedDate As String
    FormattedDate = String.Empty
    If dateToFormat > DateTime.MinValue Then
        Select Case FormatOption
            Case DateTimePatterns.ShortTimeFormat :
                FormattedDate = Format(dateToFormat, Report.Parameters!ShortTimeFormat.Value)
            Case DateTimePatterns.LongTimeFormat :
                FormattedDate = Format(dateToFormat, Report.Parameters!LongTimeFormat.Value)
            Case DateTimePatterns.ShortDateFormat :
                FormattedDate = Format(dateToFormat, Report.Parameters!ShortDateFormat.Value)
            Case DateTimePatterns.LongDateFormat : 
                FormattedDate = Format(dateToFormat, Report.Parameters!LongDateFormat.Value)
            Case DateTimePatterns.ShortDateShortTimeFormat : 
                FormattedDate = Format(dateToFormat, Report.Parameters!ShortDateFormat.Value + " " + Report.Parameters!ShortTimeFormat.Value)
            Case DateTimePatterns.LongDateShortTimeFormat :
                FormattedDate = Format(dateToFormat, Report.Parameters!LongDateFormat.Value + " " + Report.Parameters!ShortTimeFormat.Value)
            Case DateTimePatterns.ShortDateLongTimeFormat : 
                FormattedDate = Format(dateToFormat, Report.Parameters!ShortDateFormat.Value + " " + Report.Parameters!LongTimeFormat.Value)
            Case DateTimePatterns.LongDateLongTimeFormat : 
                FormattedDate = Format(dateToFormat, Report.Parameters!LongDateFormat.Value + " " + Report.Parameters!LongTimeFormat.Value)
        End Select
    End If
    Return FormattedDate
End Function
```

This is an example expression in the report used to set the formatting of a date value to a specific format:

```
=Code.FormatDate(Globals!ExecutionTime, Code.DateTimePatterns.LongDateShortTimeFormat)
```

The error on upload attempts of any reports with this ENUM is long and messy, but from what I can tell this is the meat of it: ***Statement cannot appear within an Enum body. End of Enum assumed***

I don't know much about using ENUMs and I didn't write any of this, just trying to figure out if there is something we can do to get around these errors. It should be noted that if the same report is manually uploaded to PowerBI, it uploads and runs just fine, so I don't know why during the API upload it is failing whatever validation it is doing.

Here is the entire error in case I am misinterpreting what the overall issue really is that it is trying to report:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"PaginatedReportAuthoringError","pbi.error":{"code":"PaginatedReportAuthoringError","parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"RdlWorkloadErrorCode","detail":{"
type":1,"value":"PaginatedReportAuthoringError"}},{"code":"RdlWorkloadErrorMessage","detail":{"type":1,"value":"Report is invalid. ErrorCode: rsUnexpectedCompilerError, Details: An 
unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: \"[BC30619] Statement cannot appear within an Enum body. End of Enum assumed.\"."}},{"code":"RdlWorkloadE
rrorTitle","detail":{"type":1,"value":null}},{"code":"RdlWorkloadErrorContractName","detail":{"type":1,"value":"V1_MessageContainsPiiNonTranslated"}},{"code":"RdlWorkloadErrorInternalErrorMe
ssage","detail":{"type":1,"value":null}},{"code":"RdlWorkloadErrorCulprit","detail":{"type":1,"value":"User"}},{"code":"PaginatedReportAuthoringError","detail":{"type":1,"value":"Report is 
invalid. ErrorCode: rsUnexpectedCompilerError, Details: An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: \"[BC30619] Statement cannot appear within an 
Enum body. End of Enum assumed.\"."}},{"code":"HostMode","detail":{"type":1,"value":"AutoPremium"}},{"code":"CapacityObjectId","detail":{"type":1,"value":"841ED558-4F06-4A6D-9E31-B9FB12FA96E
E"}}],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}
At C:\Users\me\Documents\Migrations\PublishRDLFilesToPowerBI_devto.ps1:36 char:15
+ ...   $report = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $header ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

After some further research on that error, I found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-powershell/issues/269) forum discussion that included an example of using the New-PowerBIReport method instead of Invoke-RestMethod. It only requires the workspace ID, full path to the local RDL, the rdl file name, and a conflict resolution option. It was able to load all my rdl's, with or without the custom ENUM code, to my PBI workspace successfully.